# Does there always exist a support vector such that $0 < a_n < C$ in SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm, constrained-optimization

I have a question about SVM training in overlapping class distributions, where we are trying to minimize
$$
\dfrac{1}{2} \Vert \mathbf w \Vert_2^2 + C \sum_{n = 1}^N \xi_n \, ,
$$
subject to $y_n(\mathbf w \cdot \boldsymbol \phi(\mathbf x_n) + b) \geq 1 - \xi_n$,
where $N$ is the number of training samples, $\xi_n \geq 0$ is a slack variable indicating whether sample $\mathbf x_n$ with label $y_n \in \{-1, 1\}$ has been misclassified or not and $C > 0$. (Specifically: If $\xi_n > 1$, then $\mathbf x_n$ lies on the wrong side of the decision boundary and is misclassified. If $0 < \xi_n \leq 1$, then $\mathbf x_n$ lies inside the margin, but on the correct side of the decision boundary. If $\xi_n = 0$, then $\mathbf x_n$ is correctly classified and is either on the margin or on the correct side of the margin.)

Using Lagrange multipliers, we equivalently seek to minimize
$$
\dfrac{1}{2} \Vert \mathbf w \Vert_2^2 + C \sum_{n = 1}^N \xi_n - \sum_{n=1}^N a_n[y_n(\mathbf w \cdot \boldsymbol \phi(\mathbf x_n) + b) - (1 - \xi_n)] - \sum_{n=1}^N \mu_n \xi_n \, ,
$$
where $a_n, \mu_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in [N]$.

Setting the derivatives over $\mathbf w, \mathbf a, b$ equal to zero and using KTT conditions, it can be shown that $0 \leq a_n \leq C$ for all $n \in [N]$ (see Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning). In the same book, it is stated that for all $n \in [N]$ such that $0 < a_n < C$, we have
$$
y_n \left(b + \sum_{m=1}^N a_m y_m \boldsymbol \phi(\mathbf x_n) \cdot \boldsymbol \phi(\mathbf x_m) \right) = 1 \, ,
$$
from which we can determine $b$.

**My question is:** Is it guaranteed that there always exists some $n \in [N]$ such that $0 < a_n < C$, so that the last equation holds (or could there be cases where $a_n$ can only be $0$ or $C$)?

Comment: A non-zero slack variable does not necessarily indicate that it has been misclassified, just that it lies within the margins (but could still be the right side of the decision boundary)

Comment: Thank you, I just added a clarification about that.

Comment: I suspect that the condition may not hold for degenerate cases (at least for some suitably chosen value of $C$), such as a univariate problem with two positive and one negative pattern at x = +1 and two negative patterns and one positive pattern at x = -1, however I don't have MATLAB at home to check it.